# Storing variables that hold an element from a file into a variable

Tags: c#

Okay, so im reading from a file and than splitting and storing the elements into different variables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7KAf.png)

I have a class called Person and im trying to store this info into a person object such as  `people.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, address));` This works fine except for the address i cant seem to figure out. You see, i have a class called Address as well which holds street, city, state, etc. I can't seem to figure out how to store the address variables i have that are loaded with the info from the file to a new variable to add to the person object. Here is some code

PERSON CLASS

```
internal class Person : IComparable<Person>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; init; }
        public string LastName { get; init; }
        public Address Address { get; init; }
        
        //constructor
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Address address)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Address = address;
        }
    }
```

ADDRESS CLASS

```
 internal class Address
    {
        public string StreetAddress { get; init; }
        public string City { get; init; }
        public string State { get; init; }
        public string PostalCode { get; init; }

        //constructor
        public Address(string streetAddress, string city, string state, string postalCode)
        {
            StreetAddress = streetAddress;
            City = city;
            State = state;
            PostalCode = postalCode;
        }
    }
```

PROGRAM

```
string root = FileRoot.Root;

string csvFile = root + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "data.csv";

string psvFile = root + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "data.psv";

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        var split = line.Split(",");

        // get and store info from file
        var firstName = split[0];
        var lastName = split[1];
        var streetAddress = split[2];
        var city = split[3];
        var state = split[4];
        var postalCode = split[5];

       // var address = (streetAddress, city, state, postalCode);
       List<Address> address = new List<Address>();
        

        people.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, address));

    }

}
```

Comment: The code in your question won't compile. Because the type `List<Address>` is not convertible to the type `Address`, obviously.

Comment: I figured as much. And just using a normal variable isn't working either so im kinda of stumped here

Comment: Look how you instantiate a Person instance. Now look at the commented out line where you seem trying to instantiate what? Do you notice a difference in pattern between these two lines?

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Originally I tried doing the same thing i did with the people.Add with address.Add but that didnt seem to work

Comment: Consider using a standard serialization (and persistence) format like JSON (or even XML). Then you can let a tested serialization library (like Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json) take care of the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the `new Address` part:

```cs
var address = new Address(streetAddress, city, state, postalCode);
people.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, address));
```

Just forget about the `List<Address>` unless you are planning on having multiple addresses for each person object.

Comment: Right okay. I'm getting some errors on this though. It's telling me the call is ambiguous and the same now for Person

Comment: Is there another constructor in your classes besides the ones shown in this question?

Comment: No, just those ones. Maybe i have duplicate files or something?

Comment: Possibly, maybe you can post the full project details but this is beyond what you were originally asking.  If you can't figure out where the ambiguous code is at, maybe ask a new question with more details.

Comment: Yup, somehow i had 2 files of each. Might have been from working on the same project from 2 different machines